# input random matrix with only " * " and " SPACE "

Tags: c, random, matrix, char

i know how to set a range but the * and SPACE are between 32 and 42 .. and i need only either one of them to input in my matrix.

```
{
int i,j;
char matrix[SIZE][SIZE],c;
srand(time(NULL));
for (i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
{
    for (j=0;j<SIZE;j++)
    {
        c=(rand()%32) || (rand()%42);
        matrix[i][j]=c;
        printf("%3c", matrix[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Get a random one or zero, and use that to decide.

Answer (score 3):

A classic method uses an array look-up:

```
c = " *"[rand() % 2];
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
c = rand() % 2 ? ' ' : '*';
```

Or, without the bad bad ternary operator

```
if( rand() % 2 ) {
    c = ' ';
}
else {
    c = '*';
}
```